# Dropping empty section \value R package check note

Tags: r, r-package

when I perform check of a package in Rstudio, I get this note "Dropping empty section \value".
It happens during the checking of the Rd files.

```
checking Rd files ... NOTE
  prepare_Rd: function.Rd:20-22: Dropping empty section \value
```

Did somebody encounter such an error, and do you know how to solve it???

All help is much appreciated...

Comment: Did you put something like that `#' @section value` in a roxygen generated doc ?

Comment: No, I did not. :(

Comment: Show us the roxygen code or the Rd file.

Answer (score 11):

This means that at least one of the fields in your *Roxygen* skeleton doesn't contain any value.

If, for instance, you are not providing any information about the return, either provide it:

```
#' @return <information>
```

or remove the whole `#' @return` line.

Comment: This worked for me, and is probably the most common mistake when writing R docs.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem - it was due to a bracket mismatch ('{' instead of '[') in the 'preamble' (i.e., the #' - section) of the file. You might want to check the log of the compilation (subdir package.Rcheck).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this error occurred, but I rewrote the @return in roxygen skeleton and know I don't get this note on checking.

If somebody is experiencing this problem as well, try rewriting @return